# Como realizar análise semântica usando programação funcional pura sem side effect?

Tags: compilação, programação-funcional, compiladores

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de saber qual o contexto atual sem usar *side effects* como `Agente` do elixir , deixando a análise semântica ser realizada ao longo de um pipeline de funções que caminham pela AST.

Algumas coisas que eu tenho mais interesse:

- Verificar se uma variável foi declarada ou não.
- Como saber qual contexto do código que está sendo analisado, por exemplo saber que a variável não existe mais depois de sair de um bloco na linguagem c:

```c
int a;
{
    int b = 0;
}
// b não está mais válida para ser usada aqui
```

[Aqui foi um pequeno compilador que eu fiz mas tenho que instanciar todas as variáveis primeiro já que possuo somente um contexto global.](https://github.com/NetonD/alguma-elixir)

Comment: desculpa mas não está muito claro, como realizar ma análise quer dizer um algoritmo? como citou um compilador, tem um código? precisa ver a lógica usada pra entender melhor, precisa dar mais detalhes

Comment: desculpa discordar mas está claro, o que preciso é realizar a análise semântica, então isso já é o suficiente para entender a pergunta, mas eu coloquei uma limitação que é realizar essa etapa da compilação usando somente recursos disponíveis em linguagens funcionais puras. Isso implica em usar somente funções e não salvar um estado externo como um objeto global para guardar o contexto atual.

Comment: Também no link disponibilizado segue minha tentativa de realizar análise semântica, mas eu "roubei" usando os `Agent` disponíveis em `Elixir` para salvar algum estado de processamento fora da função.

Comment: É uma ótima pergunta para https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Valeu pela dica, vou traduzir a pergunta e mandar lá também

Comment: Elixir e Erlang para mim é grego, vendo seu projeto não consegui descobrir como cria as estruturas de contexto, mas normalmente usa-se mapas(dicionários) encadeados que é uma pilha de estruturas chave valor onde um nome é pesquisado inicialmente ao mapa mais ao topo e  enquanto não for encontrado é então pesquisado descendo pela pilha. Sendo que o contexto em direção a base da pilha é mais amplo(global) enquanto que o contexto em direção ao topo da pilha é mais restrito(local).

Comment: Se vc se refere a AST tem dois códigos na pasta `src/`, um para o analisador léxico `lexer.xrl` e um para o parser que gera minha AST `parser.yrl`. Eu utilizo as ferramentas do erlang LEEX e o YEEC sendo que passo a saída (os tokens) do `lexer.xrl` diretamente para o `parser.yrl` produzindo a AST anotada no arquivo `compiler.ex` imediatamente antes de iniciar a tradução com a função `translate/2`. Essa mecânica é similar ao Flex/Lex + Yacc/Bison.

Comment: No codigo do link eu gero apenas e somente **um** contexto e armazeno ele dentro de um `Agent` logo no início da tradução/análise semântica, que é similar a similar a um objeto (guardada as diferenças de paradigmas e a funcionalidade em si da coisa) mas eu posso inserir e alterar estados nele, no caso eu NAO quero usar esse `Agent` para armazenar minha estrutura de contextos aninhados.

Comment: Mas com o agente sim, poderia nesse caso, fazer um push/pop no topo de uma pilha de contextos que estaria armazenada no `Agent`. Então o problema é gerar essa pilha de contextos fora do `Agent`, e um problema maior ainda é percorrer/verificar ela já que não armazeno o estado fora do `Agent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com certeza existe uma forma de fazer isso sem side effects.

A ideia é usar uma estrutura de dados stateless pra representar o contexto. A função que avalia a AST recebe o contexto anterior e devolve um novo contexto de acordo com as instruções na AST.

Sobre a questão de criar e destruir novos contextos, é muito simples, o programa não terá 1 contexto só, mas sim uma lista de contextos, aí você adiciona um novo contexto ao iniciar uma função, e remove ao finalizar a função. (Como eu disse acima, na prática você não vai realmente adicionar e remover, mas sim criar novas listas)

Eu nunca programei em Elixir, mas imagino que ela disponibilize estruturas stateless. Toda linguagem funcional disponibiliza, senão ficaria inviável de programar nelas.

Abaixo vou deixar uma implementação que fiz um JavaScript. Perceba que eu não modifico o contexto em lugar nenhum, ou seja, esse código pode ser tranquilamente convertido pra uma linguagem puramente funcional.

Deixei alguns comentários no código que serão úteis pro teu entendimento.

```js
const ast = {
    "type": "program",
    "statements": [

        // var a = 1
        {
            "type": "decl",
            "id": "a",
            "expr": {
                "type": "literal",
                "value": "1"
            }
        },

        // function f { ... }
        {
            "type": "fn",
            "id": "f",
            "statements": [

                // Variável `a` está visível pois é top-level.
                // var x = a
                {
                    "type": "decl",
                    "id": "x",
                    "expr": {
                        "type": "var",
                        "id": "a"
                    }
                },

                // Variável `x` está visível pois é do mesmo contexto.
                // var y = x
                {
                    "type": "decl",
                    "id": "y",
                    "expr": {
                        "type": "var",
                        "id": "x"
                    }
                },

            ],
        },

        // f()
        {
            "type": "fn-call",
            "id": "f",
        },

        // Variável `a` permanece visível
        // var b = a
        {
            "type": "decl",
            "id": "b",
            "expr": {
                "type": "var",
                "id": "a"
            }
        },

        // O nodo abaixo dá erro! A variável `x` não está mais acessível aqui!
        // // var c = x
        // {
        //     "type": "decl",
        //     "id": "c",
        //     "expr": {
        //         "type": "var",
        //         "id": "x"
        //     }
        // },
    ]
}

// Função helper pra deixar o código mais legível.
function last(xs) {
    return xs[xs.length - 1]
}

// Função helper pra deixar o código mais legível.
function allButLast(xs) {
    return xs.slice(0, -1)
}

// Procura em todos os contextos acumulados, ou seja, considera variáveis
// top-level.
// Apesar de usar laços de repetição, perceba que o código é stateless e pode
// ser facilmente convertido pra uma lógica recursiva.
// Perceba, ainda, que o uso do throw é muito feio, fiz assim apenas por
// simplicidade. Retorne um monada que represente a possibilidade de não
// encontrar o item, dessa forma isso fica explícito no sistema de tipos.
function findInContext(context, type, id) {
    for (const subCtx of context) {
        for (const item of subCtx) {
            if (item["type"] === type && item["id"] === id) {
                return item
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Error(`Identificador ${id} não encontrado`)
}

// Optei por separar a evaluação de expressões e de statements. Isso é gosto
// pessoal, no teu código faça como achar mais apropriado.
function evaluateExpr(expr, context) {
    switch (expr["type"]) {
        case "literal": {
            return expr["value"]
        }

        case "var": {
            const item = findInContext(context, "var", expr["id"])
            return item ? item["value"] : null
        }
    }
}

// A função `evaluate` nunca modifica o contexto, apenas gera novos contextos
// de acordo com o fluxo do programa. Totalmente stateless.
function evaluate(ast, context) {
    switch (ast["type"]) {
        case "program": {
            const newContext = [[]]
            const f = (ctx, stmt) => evaluate(stmt, ctx)
            return ast["statements"].reduce(f, newContext)
        }

        case "decl": {
            const expr = evaluateExpr(ast["expr"], context)
            const id = ast["id"]
            const item = { "type": "var", "id": id, "value": expr }
            return [...allButLast(context), [...last(context), item]]
        }

        case 'fn': {
            const id = ast["id"]
            const statements = ast["statements"]
            const item = { "type": "fn", "id": id, "statements": statements }
            return [...allButLast(context), [...last(context), item]]
        }

        case 'fn-call': {
            const func = findInContext(context, "fn", ast["id"])
            // Cria um novo contexto no qual as variáveis da função serão
            // declaradas.
            const newContext = [...context, []]
            const f = (ctx, stmt) => evaluate(stmt, ctx)
            func["statements"].reduce(f, newContext)
            // Aqui tá o pulo do gato. Ao encerrar a execução da função,
            // retorna o contexto antigo, ou seja, ignora todas as variáveis
            // que foram declaradas dentro da função.
            return context
        }
    }
}

evaluate(ast)
```